# jQuery: .each .data('key') gives "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'data'"

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.each($('input[value|="Disable Login"]'), function() {
    alert(this.data('id'));
});
```

gives

> "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'data'".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for :

```js
$('input[value|="Disable Login"]').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Also, you may consider applying it to a sub part of your document. Like this :

```js
$('input[value|="Disable Login"]',$("#myform")).each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```